# Counting the results in a mongodb cursor before limiting it

Tags: mongodb

I have a question regarding performances in mongodb. Basically let's assume we have a collection named `items` that we want to query. Of course I am going to limit the query in order not to retrieve too much stuff during one single page load. Something like this would do:

```
db.items.find(/* some condition */).sort( { timestamp : -1 } ).limit(10);
```

This is a typical example. So typical I took it straight from mongodb's website. Hahaha!

Now the real question is: can I, before limiting/sorting the data contained in the cursor, do a global count of all it is contained in the cursor? Like this:

```
var curs = db.items.find(/* some condition */);
curs.count(); // is this a resource consuming operation??? <<<
curs.sort( { timestamp : -1 } ).limit(10);
```

Or is does it become a heavy load operation as the amount of results matching the criteria in the `find` grows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count method in (most) MongoDB drivers will actually by default count WITHOUT the skip and limit.

It is in fact an additional parameter of `true` that makes it count with the skip and limit.

As such yes, you can do a global count even after doing skip and limit.

It is however, good to note that doing a count will actually perform a count in MongoDB and even though there have been numerous improvements to make counts faster they can still be extremely costly.

It depends on the size of your data but if you have in the region of 100,000's of rows in the result you shouldn't face too much of a problem.

Comment: ok so the answer is: YES! `count` does cost in terms of performances, but not toooo much and can be kinda safely used if the app does not grow too big.Correct?